# Manipular datos para ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Actualmente intento realizar unos gráficos y para ello necesito reorganizar ciertos datos. Arme una base de datos bastante grande en función de reconocidas bases de datos como v-dem, el global competitiveness index, Rule of Law, entre otras. Luego seleccioné las variables que son de interés y filtré países que responden a tres criterios de comparación respecto de Paraguay (los países de la OCDE, algunos de Latinoamerica y los países de ingresos medios-altos).

Teniendo esta base lista quería hacer algún gráfico bastante sencillo en el cual me gustaría mostrar para una variable (y luego replicarlo con algunas más) la variación que presenta, de los años para los cuales tengo datos, en función de estos tres grupos de países y Paraguay. Esto es un gráfico en donde el eje x sean los años, el eje y los valores que toma la variable, y luego tener cuatro representaciones de estos grupos. 
Cree un repositorio en github para poder visualizar la base de datos de la que hablo:
https://github.com/florenciagayraud/usaidpry

Ahora bien, realmente estoy estancada en como reorganizar los datos para este fin. Lo que debería tener es un data frame que luego utilizaré como input para ggplot en la cual pueda tener un promedio que responda a cada conjunto de países según el año. Inicialmente lo que hice para ordenarme fue crear un dataframe separado por cada grupo de país.

dataplot2 <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(ocde == 1) %>% select(country, year, Q3.2 | Independent judiciary) %>% filter(!is.na(Q3.2 | Independent judiciary))

Al ejecutar esto obtengo un data frame con tres variables: los países de la ocde, los años y la variable que deseo graficar, quedandome sólo con aquellos años para los cuales se registran datos. `>

```
head(dataplot2)

A tibble: 6 x 3
Groups: year, country [6]
country year Q3.2 | Independent judiciary
1 Chile 2006 9
2 Chile 2008 9
3 Chile 2010 9
4 Chile 2012 9
5 Chile 2014 9
6 Chile 2016 9 `
```

Lo que había pensado era agregarle un summarise que cree una variable para cada años, por ejemplo: ocde2006 y que tome como valor el promedio de la variable cuando el año sea 2006, y así sucesivamente para los años siguientes.

```
summarise(ocde2006 = sum(Q3.2 | Independent judiciary[year == 2006]).
```

Sin embargo, al hacer esto me salta un error "Error in sum(Q3.2 | Independent judiciary[year == 2006]) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument". Intenté cambiarle la clase a las variables como numeric y sigue el mismo error. Quizás hay otra manera de hacerlo Espero haber sido clara

ACTUALIZACIÓN: Ejecuté este código y funciona bastante bien, salvo el error final que implica para el grupo "uperr-middle" me devuelve NA. ¿Qué puede estar fallando?

```
> dataplot <- usaid_pry2 %>% select(country, year, `Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`) %>% 
+   mutate(grupos = case_when(country %in% c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Chile", 
+                                             "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", 
+                                             "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
+                                             "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "South Korea",
+                                             "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Mexico", 
+                                             "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", "Poland", 
+                                             "Portugal", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", 
+                                             "Switzerland", "Turkey", "United Kingdom", 
+                                             "United States of America") ~ "ocde",
+                              country %in% c("Uruguay", "Costa Rica", "Chile", "Argentina", "Panama", 
+                                             "Brazil") ~ "latam",
+                              country %in% c("Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Argentina", "Armenia",
+                                             "Azerbaijan", "Belarus", "Belize", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
+                                             "Botswana", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "China", "Colombia", "Costa Rica",
+                                             "Cuba", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", 
+                                             "Equatorial Guinea", "Fiji", "Gabon", "Georgia",
+                                             "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guyana", "Iran", "Iraq", "Jamaica", 
+                                             "Jordan", "Kazahstan", "Kosovo", "Lebanon", "Libya", "Malaysia", 
+                                             "Maldives", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Montenegro", 
+                                             "Namibia","Nauru", "North Macedonia", "Peru", "Romania",
+                                             "Russia", "Samoa", "Serbia", "South Africa", "Sri Lanka", "St. Lucia",
+                                             "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", "Suriname", "Thailand", "Tonga",
+                                             "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu","Venezuela") ~ "upper-middle",
+                             country == "Paraguay" ~ "Paraguay")) %>% 
+   filter(!is.na(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)) %>% group_by(grupos) %>% 
+   summarise(promedio_q3_bti = mean(as.numeric(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)))
Warning message:
In mean(as.numeric(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN2:
Finalmente pude resolverlo de esta manera, al graficarlo funciona muy bien.

```
dataParaguay <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(country == "Paraguay") %>% 
  select(country, year, `Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`) %>% filter(!is.na(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% summarise(mean_pry_year=mean(as.numeric(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)))

dataocde <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(ocde == 1) %>% select(country, year, `Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)) %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_ocde_year=mean(as.numeric(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)))

datalatam <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(latam == 1) %>% select(country, year, `Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)) %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_latam_year=mean(as.numeric(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)))

datauppermid <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(upper-middle == 1) %>% select(country, year, `Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)) %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_uppermid_year=mean(as.numeric(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`)))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + geom_point(dataParaguay, mapping = aes(x = year, y = mean_pry_year, color = "Paraguay")) +
  geom_point(data = dataocde, mapping = aes(x = year, y = mean_ocde_year, color = "OCDE")) +
  geom_point(data = datalatam, mapping = aes(x = year, y = mean_latam_year, color = "Latam")) + 
  geom_point(data = datauppermid, mapping = aes(x = year, y = mean_uppermid_year, color = "upper-middle"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma quizas es creando una variable agrupando por anios primero y despues creando el promedio de cada anio para otra columna.En tu caso seria:

dataplot2%>%group_by(year)%>%summarise(mean_ocde_year=Q3.2 | Independent judiciary);

Saludos

Comment: Creo que no te funcionaba porque me parece (soy medio nuevo con R), intentabas utilizar summarise como si fuera un filter y al mismo timepo crear la variable. Debe haber una forma de hacerlo, pero hasta ahora conozco lo que te pase

Comment: Funcionó muy bien, lo utilicé del modo que edité la respuesta. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada!! poneme la respuesta como correcta ; )

Answer (score 0):

Si en primera instancia solo quieres ver la variación de una variable en el tiempo, el comando ts.plot es el indicado (dependiendo de como esten ordenados los datos, serie de tiempo es la traducción del comando), ahora bien, si tienes fechas, mi consejo es que primero esas fechas las pases a as.character(fecha en cualquier formato) y después acorde a ese formato veas que comando del paquete lubridate te sirve (busca lubridate en R y te va a salir de todo)

Si quieres automatizar todo, onda dividir en primera instancia tus datos por paises, aconsejo crear una función en la cual le entregues una lista con los nombres de estos y que por medio de un for que vaya por cada elemento de esa listay te retorne otra lista de listas con los datos divididos por paises, después otra función que reciba esta nueva lista y que tome cada elemento (perteneciente a un país en particular) y que haga lo que tu busques que haga, o una ts.plot() con un lubridate para una columna de fechas en caso que las tengas y con un summary en caso que quieras ver las estadisticas generales de esos datos, espero ser de ayuda, si no pregunta no más, igual en algo me manejo en R

Answer (score 0):

El tema son los valores faltantes, siempre es bueno una vista rápida de que es lo que contiene una variable, por ejemplo:

```
> table(usaid_pry2$`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`, useNA="ifany") 

    -     1    10     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9  <NA> 
    3     2    23    29    20    52    56    52    31    31    82 13787
```

Tienes 13.787 valores faltantes, y 3 observaciones donde el valor parece un guión. Deberías revisar estos casos ya que son potencialmente peligrosos.

De cualquier forma, con respecto a tu pregunta, una solución es hacer que `mean()` ignore los valores `NA`, pero claro, tiene que ser válido para tu análisis hacer esto.

```
summarise(promedio_q3_bti = mean(as.numeric(`Q3.2 | Independent judiciary`), na.rm = TRUE))
```